# Creating table from json using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, unique

First of all I'm pretty new to javascript. I tried to create a table from json file. I read up some information and follow some tutorials, and I finally was able to create a table that appeared on the web browser. But I found out that the different arrays are always sorted, and it allows only unique values. For example here is the json:

```
var json = {
            "data": [
                {
                    "number": "13",
                    "position": "GK",
                    "name": "John"
                },
                {
                    "number": "2",
                    "position": "CB",
                    "name": "Bill"
                },
                {
                    "number": "26",
                    "position": "CB",
                    "name": "Nick"
                }
```

And when I put the information in the table I'm creating it looks something like this:

```
| Number | Position | Name |
|   2    |    GK    | John |
|   13   |    CB    | Bill |
|   26   |undefined | Nick |
```

As you can see the numbers from json file does not match their names and the numbers are sorted, for example `John` is not number `2` but number `13`. The other thing is it doesnt allow same values - there are 2 `CB` positions, but it shows only 1 and the other is shown as `undefined`.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
     JSONDataLouder = {
     getPlayers: function(json) {
      var object = {
        "number": {}
        , "position": {}
        , "name": {}
    };

    var personData = null; 
    for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        personData = json.data[i];
        object.number[personData.number] = 1;
        object.position[personData.position] = 1;
        object.name[personData.name] = 1;
    }

    var u = {
        "number": []
        , "position": []
        , "name": []
    };

    for(var k in object.number) u.number.push(k);
    for(var k in object.position) u.position.push(k);
    for(var k in object.name) u.name.push(k);


    return u;

}

,getTable: function(json) {

    var obj = this.getPlayers(json);

    var number = obj.number;
    var position = obj.position;
    var name = obj.name;

    var table = this.createTable();


    var headerRow = table.insertRow();
    headerRow.insertCell().innerHTML = "Number";
    headerRow.insertCell().innerHTML = "Position";
    headerRow.insertCell().innerHTML = "Name"


    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        var secondRow = table.insertRow();
        secondRow.style.textAlign="center";
        secondRow.insertCell().innerHTML = number[i];
        secondRow.insertCell().innerHTML = position[i];
        secondRow.insertCell().innerHTML = name[i];

    }

    return table;
}


,render: function(mainDiv) {

    $( mainDiv ).empty();
    var json = {
        "data": [
            {
                "number": "13",
                "position": "GK",
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "number": "2",
                "position": "CB",
                "name": "Bill"
            },
            {
                "number": "26",
                "position": "CB",
                "name": "Nick"
            }
```

I know I misunderstood something when learning about pushing objects into array, and I tried to change it in any way, but it still appeares the same. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Parsed `json` is not `json`. Why literally everybody calls javascript object `json`?

Comment: Sound like [javascript templates](http://handlebarsjs.com/)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem that you are experiencing is that in javascript, hashes are not ordered, so when you do `for(var k in object.number)`, you can not expect each number to come out in the same order that you put it in.

Arrays, however will preserve order.

I don't think you need your `object` variable at all. I think you can just do this:

```
JSONDataLouder = {
  getPlayers: function(json) {

  var u = {
    "number": [],
    "position": [],
    "name": []
  };

  var personData; 
  for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    personData = json.data[i];
    u.number.push(personData.number);
    u.position.push(personData.position);
    u.name.push(personData.name);
  }

  return u;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I guess I went really into data structures as `barry-johnson` suggested, and ignored that there is simpler sollution. Thank you for your fast answer.

Answer (score 2):

Different test data would like give you even crazier results. There are actually a lot of issues in the code, but I think the main thing getting you off track is mixing your data structures. Before you think about the table itself, think about your intermediate data structure, namely some sort of (in effect) two dimensional array.

The thing is though, that you don't need an intermediate structure. You already have an array in your JSON.data. In your code, you are converting this array into something else.

Consider the following, which omits some of what you are doing, but cuts to the core of the table generation.

```
var json = {
    "data": [
        {
            "number": "13",
            "position": "GK",
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "number": "2",
            "position": "CB",
            "name": "Bill"
        },
        {
            "number": "26",
            "position": "CB",
            "name": "Nick"
        }
    ]
};


function objToTable(obj) {
    var data = obj.data;
    var output = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        output += '<tr>';
        output += '<td>' + data[i].number + '</td>';
        output += '<td>' + data[i].position + '</td>';
        output += '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>';
        output += '</tr>\n'; // added newline for console readability
    }
    output += '</table>';
    return output;
}


console.log(objToTable(json));
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Yes, I know the code is really bad, and at some point illogical, but I'm still trying to figure it out. I'll look more into what you suggested and start working from there.

Comment: You're welcome. @BananaNeil's suggestion is quite clean as well. Regarding the code, I think part of the issue was just a partial copy/paste. Have fun with the learning, and BTW this was a good SO question - includes the code you've tried, what you're trying to do, etc. Keep asking questions that way and you will never be short for help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could help you

```js
    var json = {
      "data": [
        {
          "number": "13",
          "position": "GK",
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "number": "2",
          "position": "CB",
          "name": "Bill"
        },
        {
          "number": "26",
          "position": "CB",
          "name": "Nick"
        }]
      };
        
        console.log('|  Número  |  Posición  |  Nombre  |');

        $.each(json.data, function(id, item)
        {
         
             console.log(item.number + '|' + item.position + '|' + item.name + '|');
        
        });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```